# Route 53 Sub Domain - EC2 Instance Issue

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, jira, amazon-route53, confluence

I am fairly new to AWS and have been trying to solve a problem. The problem statement; the company i work for currently have a cloud subscription with Atlassian for Jira and Confluence products. They want to move to a self-hosted license and so asked me to see what could be done.

I did the following steps:

1. Setup an Amazon Ec2 Instance
2. Associated an Elastic IP
3. In Route 53 I created a zone and did the necessary with Go Daddy to add name servers.
4. I installed Jira on the EC2 instance
5. I installed Confluence on the EC2 Instance

Now for the sake of this let's say my instance domain is ec2compute.amazonaws.com. Jira installed on port 8080 and confluence on 8090. If I navigate in my browser to ec2compute.amazonaws.com:8080 and ec2compute.amazonaws.com:8090 I get to the setup pages of Jira and Confluence.

So working as expected so far. Except I want to use my own domain - more importantly a sub-domain for Jira and a sub-domain for Confluence.

Going back to my domain, as I said i set the domain up lets say example.com in Route 53 and did the go daddy nameserver assignment. I installed apache on Ec2 and now if i go example.com i get the apache welcome page on my server...and if i go to example.com:8080 I get to the jira page and example.com:8090 i get to the confluence page.

What I want to do though is point jira.example.com to get to the jira page and confluence.example.com to get to the confluence page. I have tried updated the httpd.conf file with a virtual host for each but with no success.

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do (you can put it at the bottom of the `httpd.conf` or, even better, as separate `.conf` file in `conf.d` subfolder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName confluence.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **proxies** when installing Confluence and Jira on the same server. To actually configure Confluence and Jira at separate urls, you'll also edit each app's `server.xml` (among other things). Atlassian has documents that instruct on [Using Apache with mod_proxy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/using-apache-with-mod_proxy-173669.html?_ga=2.140436791.528055166.1557289927-1719279149.1557289927) and [Proxying Atlassian server applications with Apache HTTP Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html).